# Improper integral proof to -inf to inf

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  $f$ is continuous and positive on $\mathbb R$.
Prove that integral

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (1+x^2)^t f(x)\,dx $$

convegent => integral -inf to inf $f(x)dx$ ; convergent.
(t is any positive number)
There are two variables -inf and inf.
So I can't use the monotonic convergence thm.
ㅠㅅㅠ

Comment: Break up into two integrals, apply Comparison to each.

Comment: I think there is no condition for two integrals; convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break up the integral into two parts, the integral from $0$ to $\infty$, and the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$. We show that $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges. A similar argument will take care of the other integral.

We have $0\le f(x)\le (1+x^2)^t f(x)$. Thus, since $\int_0^\infty (1+x^2)^t f(x)\,dx$ converges, so does $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Oh, I see!  The given function is positive! Thank you!!!!!!!